# java getter/setter just one method, to access a classes field

Tags: java

Got a quick design question.
I try to implement a "theoretical" machine. Inside the virtual CPU's virtual EXEC-UNIT i wrote a class representing a Register. The registerfile can be read and written at the same time. So i would facy this java:

```
public int getSetValue(boolean w, int v);
```

Invokation will return the current value and in case of w = true, replacing the old value with v. Do you agree with my methods signature and name?

Comment: Why not have a get() method and a getAndSet(int newValue) method? Some core Java classes like java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger are doing exactly that.

Comment: if I had to do a `getSetValue()` method, I would do it passing the wrapper Class of the data type. That way, you just have to check for a `null` value or not in the method and not have to use a boolean to determine if the method is to be used as a `get` or a `set`: `public int getSetValue (Int v);`. But that's just my thought.

Comment: `getSet` suggests, return me the current value and apply the new value, not sure if that's your intention...

Comment: I just want to write code that can be understood quickly. Thank you for pointing me to that Java, Carsten. I totally agree with what they did.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure really if there is a question here. Or a clear intent for this code. Please show people who you want help from the full code along with a good explanation. As far as your question. Do you agree with my methods signature and name. The name seems acceptable as long as you can remember and type it easily. And if it is my intent you want to check if w is true and change v if it is yeah I dont see why you would want to change the parameters.